# Disabling manual inputs for KendoUI elements

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using few KendoUI elements like ComboBox, DatePicker etc. everything works fine but there is one major problem that these elements actually allow manual input.

For e.g. in the comboBox I can type by clicking on it which activates a text box, which is really dangerous and spoils the purpose of using a `<select>` type list elements, same is the case with date picker.

So can you guide how can I disable these manual inputs and only restrict user to the select from the available options.

```
<input id="date" value="@DateTime.Now.Date"/>
<select name="need" id="need">
                            <option value="1">High</option>
                            <option value="2">Normal</option>
                            <option value="3">Low</option>
                        </select>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $("#date").kendoDatePicker();
     $("#need").kendoComboBox();
</script>
```

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the datepicker is disabled it will not be submitted to the server. Better use the **[readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)** attribute instead.

Comment: If you are binding a model and use ajax to save the data only, then disable should work right? This fails only in the case where we have a postback?

Answer (score 3):

to deny manual input you need the access to the input textbox inside the telerik template:

```
var input = $(#"combobox").data("kendoComboBox").input;
input.attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want users to type in text , use the [DropDownList](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/index.html) instead of the combobox. For date picker you can easily disable the input element which you are converting to date picker using jQuery.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whizkid747/7D7B7/):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        // create DatePicker from input HTML element
          var datepicker =      $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
          $("#datepicker").prop('disabled', true);
            });
```

Comment: Thankyou, DropDownList is what i required. However Disabling the datePicker isn't actually posting it to the server `readonly` is what was required there.

Answer (score 0):

dropdownbox() works that way instead of combobox() if case is not editable combobox.